# Suddenly npm install and update fails with "node-gyp"-errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

after 2 weeks of holiday with no changes in my code i am not longer able to install or update my node_modules per npm. And i have no idea what happend here.

No changes in Code, maybe a windows update, but everything else is exactly like it was before, but doesn`t work anymore.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\project-management-webapp\ui\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.5 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.33927.289) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project-management-webapp\\ui\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.17.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.17.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\hp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.17.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project-management-webapp\\ui\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project-management-webapp\\ui\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\xampp\htdocs\project-management-webapp\ui\node_modules\@parcel\watcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\project-management-webapp\ui\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```